# my code is throwing a indent error and i cant find the problem

Tags: python, pyqt5

i am using the pyqt5 module and its throwing a indent error here is the bit of code that's throwing the error

i have tried to place the block after the text browser variable

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

 with open("data.txt", "a+") as data_file:
 try:
     for text in data_file:
         textBrowser.append(text)
 else:
     for texts in data_file:
         textBrowser.append(texts)`
```

Comment: Looking at the source view, it doesn't look like you indented the `with` body, and there's a weird single extra leading space on most of your lines that may or may not have been introduced in the process of trying to post this. Also, your `try` doesn't have an `except` or `finally`, and it's not clear why you have a `try` at all.

Comment: Python is rather picky about indentation, please have at look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out).

Comment: A relevant code editor that understands python would catch this error. The excellent [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your indentation but the correct form of try-else IMO is try-except-else. Like this:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    ...
else:
    ...
```